# Datatable does not sort elements in primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Any idea why the sorting does not work?

```
<h:form prependId="false">

<p:dataTable value="#{questionBackingBean.questions}"
        var="question" id="questionTable" paginator="true" rows="15"
        paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
        rowsPerPageTemplate="15,25,50" paginatorPosition="bottom">


<p:column sortBy="#{question.id}">
    <f:facet name="header">ID</f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{question.id}" />
</p:column>
<p:column sortBy="#{question.description}">
    <f:facet name="header">Description</f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{question.description}" />
</p:column>
</h:form>
```

**Question entity**

```
@Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + id;
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!(obj instanceof Question)) {
            return false;
        }
        Question other = (Question) obj;
        if (id != other.id) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

**Backing bean**

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class QuestionBackingBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject
    private QuestionLocal questionBean;
    private List<Question> questions;
    @Inject
    private Question question;
    private int questionParamId;

    public List<Question> getQuestions() {
        questions = questionBean.findAllQuestions();

        return questions;
    }

    public void setQuestions(List<Question> questions) {
        this.questions = questions;
    }

    public Question getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }

    public void setQuestion(Question question) {
        this.question = question;
    }

    public int getQuestionParamId() {
        return questionParamId;
    }

    public void setQuestionParamId(int questionParamId) {
        this.questionParamId = questionParamId;
    }

    public void init() {
        question = questionBean.findQuestion(questionParamId);
    }

    public String addQuestion() {
        questionBean.createQuestion(question);
        return "../index.xhtml";
    }
}
```

Comment: The sort by should be an attribute on the managed bean and then before you return the result you can sort it.

Comment: Your sortby should be an field on the managed bean that holds the column name that you want to sortBy not the value of the current row.

Comment: In Question class is there not the methods getId and getDescription? Can you post the questionBackingBean class?

Comment: There are getters/setters for all fields in the question entity class. updated with question backing bean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are returning a new list everytime getQuestions is called, doing this in JSF is a bad practice and slows down your app as getters are called multiple times in request lifecycle especially in data iteration. Cache your questions list in a property, getter should just return the questions not load them.

Your list is sorted actually in apply request values phase but you return a new instance when a getter is called again in latter phases you the sorted list is gone during processing.

Comment: Ah, thank you. But where should I fetch the list of data then from the database? Should I do it in @PostConstruct delegate method? And what happens if a new question is added to the database? Then the question will not be shown in the list before the backing bean is created again

Answer (score 1):

You should never put business logic in getter

```
public List<Question> getQuestions() {
        questions = questionBean.findAllQuestions();

        return questions;
    }
```

change it to

```
public List<Question> getQuestions() {
        return questions;
    }
```

and

```
public QuestionBackingBean(){
 this.questions = questionBean.findAllQuestions();
};
```

As you are using @ViewScope the constructor will get called every time you refresh so you have latest data.

Comment: This answer was already given by Cagatay. Unlike in old fashioned discussion forums, you do here on a Question&Answer site not need to repeat an already given answer on agreement which would only add clutter and noise. You just upvote the already given answer.

Comment: Catagaty never mentioned that this should be done in the constructor. You better see the comment by LuckyLuke.

Comment: I think its better to give an example along with detailed explanation which Cagatay is missing in his answer.