# JSF lifecycle runs 7 times on page refresh

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, lifecycle

My web page has a primefaces datatable with a simple backing bean. I use a phase listener to log what is happening behind the scenes. Lo and behold, this simple page runs the JSF lifecyle no fewer than 7 times on every page refresh!!!  What is going on?

```
<p:dataTable id="readers" var="reader" value="#{readerManagerBean.texts}" 
   rowKey="#{reader.id}" selection="#{readerBean.selectedText}" 
   selectionMode="multiple">  

  <p:column headerText="Reader Name" width="820">
      <h:outputText value="#{reader.name}" />
   </p:column>

</p:dataTable>
```

And here is the backing bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class ReaderManagerBean {

private ArrayList<Text> texts;
private Text selectedText;
@EJB
private TextFacade t;

public Text getSelectedText() {
    return selectedText;
}

public void setSelectedText(Text selectedText) {
    this.selectedText = selectedText;
}

public ArrayList<Text> getTexts() {
    ArrayList<Text> texts = new ArrayList<Text>();
    texts.addAll(t.findAll());
    return texts;
}

public void setTexts(ArrayList<Text> texts) {
    this.texts = texts;
}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by *lifecycle runs no fewer than 7 times*? Do you know that JSF lifecycle can be split into 6 *phases*, so if you decide to log before and after each phase there will be a total of 12 log events *on single page load*? Besides, where is your `PhaseListener`?

Comment: The phase listener is declared in faces-config.xml.  What I mean is that the entire lifecycle of six phases is executed 7 times on every page refresh. A tad inefficient. I want to understand why.

Comment: Post your phase listener and setup and describe what is your environment so that we'd be able to reproduce your problem.

Comment: The phase listener is irrelevant. All it does it print "Phase is: " + event.getPhaseId().toString(); in the beforePhase method. So it tells me which phases have executed. Like I say, the thing executes the whole lifecycle 7 times. If I use a bog simple page with no images or scripts I only get Restore_View and Render_Response executing. So there is something about the code I posted above that makes it run 7 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh... My... God...

By trial and error I've found out what's going on.

For the sake of brevity, I did not include all the code in my facelets page. Believe it or not, I get an entire JSF lifecycle running for every css page I link and every image I load. And it's all taking place in the head tag:

```
    <h:head>
    <link href="../resources/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../resources/css/cssLayout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../resources/javascript/main.js"/>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var preLoad = new Array();
        preLoad[0] = new Image();
        preLoad[0].src = '../resources/img/play_normal.png';
        preLoad[1] = new Image();
        preLoad[1].src = '../resources/img/play_hover.png';
        preLoad[2] = new Image();
        preLoad[2].src = '../resources/img/play_pressed.png';

        function switchImage(whichImage, imageNumber){
            document.images[whichImage].src = preLoad[imageNumber].src;
        }    
    </script>
</h:head>
```

So my revised question is this:  how can I prevent these trivial lines of code executing the whole lifecycle?

Comment: I have made progress!  I have replaced the following:
    `<link href="../resources/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`
with this:
`<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="default.css" />`

Lo and behold, one less JSF lifecycle. And so on for the others. I'm now down from 8 lifecycles to just 3.

Comment: I am using <link>-Tags to CSS too, and I tried to reproduce your problem. But I do *not* get extra phase listener calls per linked CSS. May I ask/guess: Are you mapping '**' or '*.css' to the Faces Servlet in web.xml? Mine is only: <servlet-mapping><servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>  <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern> </servlet-mapping>

Answer (score 2):

Seven calls to your bean are not the problem and JSF is doing it that way. I see a design problem here:

```
public ArrayList<Text> getTexts() {
    ArrayList<Text> texts = new ArrayList<Text>();
    texts.addAll(t.findAll());
    return texts; }
```

Do not (re-)create your list in the getter of the backing bean! Your Primefaces datatable will not be sortable. You have to return the *same* List instance on all calls.

A simple solution would be to cache the list and create it lazily.

See this answer by the Primefaces god and lead developer: [Datatable does not sort elements in primefaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189035/datatable-does-not-sort-elements-in-primefaces)

Comment: Thanks for this. It doesn't solve this particular problem, but I will implement what you say for the sake of good design and to obviate similar problems arising in the future.